# AngularJS ngRepeat comment tags build up if ngAnimate is loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

#### Edit: I have massively stripped down the project to the bare minimum and it seems to be related to `ngAnimate`. Question re-written accordingly.

I have a problem wth `ng-repeat` comments building up over time, so I end up with hundreds of them. This only happens if `ngAnimate` is loaded.

Versions:

```
"angular": "1.2.13",
"angular-animate": "~1.2.13"
```

JS:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.items = []

  $interval(function(){    
    $scope.items = [{
        "name": "Thing 1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Thing 2"
      }];
  },2000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>       
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ul ng-controller="MessagesCtrl">
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the `$interval` fires Angular repeatedly outputs `<!--end ngRepeat..,` comment tags before the closing `</ul>`:

```
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in items -->
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in items -->
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in items -->
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in items -->
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in items -->
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in items -->
```

(number of comments increases indefinitely over time)

**Removing the `ngAnimate` from the app removes the problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug in Angular 1.2.13. It was fixed in 1.2.14:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6403